# Remove Maynard and cgroups

Tags: raspbian, maynard

A while ago I tried Maynard, and while it may have looked OK it didn't actually do anything, and broke a few things (mostly GUI icons). I managed to remove most of these, but I still get the following unusual message on boot. It doesn't actually seem to cause any problems, but my question is what the following mean, and how to remove them.

```
[info] Initializing cgroups
[warn] Kernel lacks cgroups or memory controller not available, not starting cgroups....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten about this question, but eventually researched and discovered that cgroups support had been added to the kernel which can give notification of impending out of memory (OOM) events. http://www.raspberrypi.org/web-browser-beta/

I added `cgroup_enable=memory` to `cmdline.txt` which got rid of the warning.

I recently installed the latest NOOBS/Raspbian and this has similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it works...

1. open: `sudoedit /boot/cmdline.txt`
2. before `elevator=deadline` write: `cgroup_enable=memory 3`
3. save and exit: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: Any chance of getting an explanation what the digit "3" in `cgroup_enable=memory 3` means? Without such explanation, this answer provides no new info.